# FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to login a user to my app using his username and password. I read about `Create Custom Tokens`
and `Authenticate with Firebase in JavaScript Using a Custom Authentication System` but still was confused how to implement it so I tried a different approach. When the user inserts his username, app will search in Firestore collection if such username exists and if it is so, take the `email` field for that user and pass to the method `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);` I am getting the above error because I do not respect `Cloud Firestore Data model` where the structure should be `collection - document - collection - document`.

How should I proceed in such case?

My Firestore schema looks like this

```
users
 - username1
     - userId
     - email
 - username2
     - userId
     - email
```

JavaScript code

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  };
  ...

  let email;
  db.doc(`/users/${user.username}`).get()
  .then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      email = db.doc(`/users/${user.username}/email`).get();
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, user.password)
      .then((data) => {
        return data.user.getIdToken();
      }) 
      .then((token) => {
        return res.json({token});
      })
      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Document references must have an even number of segments" has nothing to do with Firebase Authentication.  It's telling you that your code to build a document reference is incorrect:

```
db.doc(`/users/${user.username}/email`)
```

Here, your document reference has three segments (an odd number).  Document references must have an even number.

Since you've already read the user document, there is no need to read anything else.  If you want the email address out of the [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) that you already have, just get it directly:

```
if (doc.exists) {
  email = doc.data().email;
```

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) about reading documents from Firestore.